# How to use MongoDb Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this
orders:

```
{ "_id": 123 , 
"order" : { "orderId": 100, "name": "John Doe" }, 
"deliverTo": [ "A", "B", "C"] }
```

deliveries:

```
{ "_id": 456 , 
"orderId": 100, 
"deliveredTo": "A"
}

{ "_id": 457 , 
"orderId": 100, 
"deliveredTo": "B"
}
```

with aggregation pipeline `$lookup` i got it to this stage

```
{"_id": 123,
"deliverTo": [ "A", "B", "C"],
"orderDeliveries": [ 
{"_id": 457 , "orderId": 100,"deliveredTo": "B"},
{"_id": 456 , "orderId": 100, "deliveredTo": "A"}] }
```

It is not delivered to address C and
how can i  achieve to query all the orders that have missing deliveries like this (might also get the count but it is optional) ?

Im new to MongoDb and Aggregation Framework and could not find a way for it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) aggregation and [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator like this.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "deliveries",
      localField: "order.orderId",
      foreignField: "orderId",
      as: "orderDeliveries"
    }
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: [
        {
          $setIsSubset: [
            "$deliverTo",
            "$orderDeliveries.deliveredTo"
          ]
        },
        "$$PRUNE",
        "$$KEEP"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZsO3bE7NkGy)

Test:

Sample collections:

```
db={
  "orders": [
    {
      "_id": 123,
      "order": {
        "orderId": 100,
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      "deliverTo": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 124,
      "order": {
        "orderId": 101,
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      "deliverTo": [
        "D",
        "E"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "deliveries": [
    {
      "_id": 456,
      "orderId": 100,
      "deliveredTo": "A"
    },
    {
      "_id": 457,
      "orderId": 100,
      "deliveredTo": "B"
    },
    {
      "_id": 458,
      "orderId": 101,
      "deliveredTo": "D"
    },
    {
      "_id": 459,
      "orderId": 101,
      "deliveredTo": "E"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 123,
    "deliverTo": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ],
    "order": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "orderId": 100
    },
    "orderDeliveries": [
      {
        "_id": 456,
        "deliveredTo": "A",
        "orderId": 100
      },
      {
        "_id": 457,
        "deliveredTo": "B",
        "orderId": 100
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hey @SuleymanSah that worked perfectly for my first question description, but there is a dumb mistake by me actually the question was wrong with deliveries i edited it would you have a chance to look at it please. Every successfull delivery is actually a separate document.

Comment: @FatihDeniz you can check the updated answer. And please don't forget to mark it as answer if it works for you.